# Having issues with MongoDB in the command prompt

Tags: javascript, mongodb, server, react-redux, backend

I am having issues verifying that I am properly running MongoDB from my command prompt.

C:\Users\Calvi\Documents\server>mongod
'mongod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have tried adding the MongoDB downloaded folder to my project (worth a shot). I have looked at the old stack overflow post but I can not seem to find the file in the downloaded Mongo folder needed to make the system variables changes. I have also tried randomly clicking on things just to see if I could get it to work. I think the new windows ten download is messing with me. Would anyone know how I could fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/varPO.png)

Comment: Share screenshot of contents of server folder

Comment: Maybe check folder `C:\Users\Calvi\Documents\server\bin`

Comment: I put an image in the original post, that way you can see what I am talking about wak786